# Opengl rotation matrix pivot animation

Tags: opengl, animation, matrix, rotation, rotational-matrices

```
        1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, cos(theta), -sin(theta), 0,
        0, sin(theta), cos(theta), 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1;
```

I'm trying to create a 'swinging' animation using a rectangular prism. The animation is very basic: The prism is going to swing back and forth, like the arms of [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_tw_7AlEdK7U/SVBT23n20_I/AAAAAAAAAE0/6C1Xxc7udew/s400/1.gif) robot toy. I need to use the above matrix.

I just need help figuring out a series of values for theta that can be plugged into this matrix in order to cause the rectangular prism it will be applied to to swing back and forth, like in the image linked to above.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use lerping (linear-interpolation) to get a smooth animation. Its hard to tell from the image but min/max pair of -35 and +35 degrees might do the trick.

Edit: Lerping

Using a value between 0 and 1 with a small increment will give you incremental positions inbetween your min and max values, called a and b in the formula below...

```
0 >= t <= 1

x = b * t + (1 - t) * a
```

Comment: I'm very aware of linear interpolation, and already have a working interpolation system. I just need some key values.

Comment: Ok, Give those a shot. They values I gave assume that your models coordinate system points the Y-axis strait down. If this isn't right for your model you can use (180 + 35) and (180 - 35).